# Why can't brand enums be unioned in Typescript 3?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use brand enums to get nominal typing in Typescript 3 (See [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html) for a description of this pattern).

The following code works fine in both TS 2.8 and 3.0.3:

```
export enum WidgetIdBrand {}
export type WidgetId = WidgetIdBrand & string;

const id:WidgetId = '123' as WidgetId;
```

However, in TS 3.0.3 when WidgetId is unioned with some other types, the WidgetId isn't retained. The compiler seems to be collapsing (EnumType & string) into `never`, but *only when in a union*.

```
const id2: WidgetId | null = id;
// Type 'WidgetId' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

However, some other kinds of union work fine:

```
const id1: WidgetId = id;                   // works
const id2: WidgetId | null = id;            // error
const id3: WidgetId | undefined = id;       // error
const id4: WidgetId | number = id;          // works!?
const id5: WidgetId | boolean = id;         // error
const id6: WidgetId | { kind: 'bar' } = id; // error
const id7: WidgetId | {} = id;              // works!?
```

Is there a way to make brand enums work in unions in TS 3?

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error I found a solution. The problem seems to be that the empty brand enum is being treated as extending `number`, and `number & string` collapses into `never` when unioned with other types.

The solution is to add an unused string value to the brand enum so that it extends `string` (and at this point the brand enum can be elided entirely).

The following code all works:

```
export enum WidgetId { _unused = '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'}

const id:WidgetId = '123' as WidgetId;

const id1: WidgetId = id;                   
const id2: WidgetId | null = id;            
const id3: WidgetId | undefined = id;       
const id4: WidgetId | number = id;          
const id5: WidgetId | boolean = id;         
const id6: WidgetId | { kind: 'bar' } = id; 
const id7: WidgetId | {} = id;
```

Comment: FTR, [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25730) has more information about why `number & string` becomes `never` in a union.